# Sending a Float32x4 array to dart VM from native host using dart ports

Tags: c++, dart

I'm trying to send a large (~3 MB array of vector data from my native c++ host to its embedded  dart VM using the async (Send/ReceivePort) pattern described in https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/

My goal is to transfer a native c++ vector of Float32x4 to a typed dart Float32x4List object in one go.

All is well and jolly when I try and send integer arrays, and i was able to run the example in the tutorial, but when i try to construct a native Dart_CObject as in:

```
Dart_CObject obj;
obj.type = Dart_CObject_kTypedData;
obj.value.as_typed_data.type = Dart_TypedData_kFloat32x4;
obj.value.as_typed_data.values = &myData;
obj.value.as_typed_data.length = myDataLength;
Dart_PostCObject(reply_port_id, &obj);
```

I get:

> vm/dart_api_message.cc:1105: error: unimplemented code

Since it seems that currently only `Dart_TypedData_kUInt8` and `Dart_TypedData_kInt8` appear to be ready for serialisation.

Is there a work-around for this? i.e. is there a way to push my native data to the dart VM as a uint8 blob and re-interpreting that buffer in dart as a Float32x4List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the data to Dart as an `Uint8List` and use the [`Float32x4List.view`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-typed_data.Float32x4List@id_Float32x4List-view) constructor to re-interpret the data as an `Float32x4List`. E.g.

```
Uint8List data = ...
Float32x4List view = new Float32x4List.view(data.buffer)
...
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. Cheers!